# error C2514: 'BLOCK' : CLASS HAS NO CONSTRUCTOR

Tags: c++

I get the error `error C2514: 'BLOCK' : CLASS HAS NO CONSTRUCTOR`  with a simple class like this:

BLOCK.h

```
#pragma once
#include "helpful.h"

class WORLD;

class BLOCK
{
    public:
        short int type;

        void Render();

        BLOCK();
        ~BLOCK(void);
};
```

BLOCK.cpp

```
#include "BLOCK.h"
#include "WORLD.h"

BLOCK::BLOCK(void)
{
}
void BLOCK::Render()
{
}
BLOCK::~BLOCK(void)
{
}
```

But the `BLOCK` class is defined, no?

Comment: Your MYCLASS has no constructor. This is BLOCK class, not MYCLASS.

Comment: `BLOCK` or `WORLD` is not `MYCLASS`: there is a piece of code missing from your post, or the error does not relate to this at all...

Answer (score 3):

I found my mistake: The call to `BLOCK`'s constructor was in another file, but the header for `BLOCK` wasn't included, all I had was `class BLOCK;`. Changed it instead to `#include BLOCK.h`, problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look for it in `MYCLASS`

Comment: sorry in fact it's not MYCLASS but BLOCK

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN, error C2514 is raised when:

> The class, structure, or union has no
>   constructor with a parameter list that
>   matches the parameters being used to
>   instantiate it.

My guess is that you're not passing the right parameters to your class' constructor. The code that raised the error is obviously not part of what you have shown.

Comment: The that calls the constructor is blocklist[nb]=new BLOCK(); I also tried to add parameters to the declaration, definition and call but I get the same error, is it a bug ?